# Two NICs on same network - one for internet, one for LAN

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet

I have two NICs in my home server - both are connected to same network. One is 2.5Gbps (which I'd like to use for LAN - **eth0**), other is 1Gbps (which I'd like to use for internet-only - **enp0s25**).

What I'd want to do is to route all internet traffic through one of them and second one to be used only for LAN connections.

My idea is to use second NIC only for local traffic in order to not interrupt the first one that's used for internet connection (in order to not bottleneck it).

How could I do this? I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with netplan.

My current configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.184/24]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ideal**

The ideally solution for what you want, is to use vlan's.  Do you know if you switch supports vlans?

You would have your internet connected to a port, on that port you would set it to be a access port on a vlan eg 5, and you can do the same on the port that connects to enp0s25.  This would put all the internet traffic on its own vlan.

The below config will work both with and without vlans, you will have to be careful that there is only one DHCP server on the network, if you are not using vlans.  With vlans you can have a dhcp server per vlan.

**Setup**

You then would setup eth0 with a staic ip, by adding the followign to the bottom of your netplan config:

```
eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.2.1/24]
```

If you wanted a dhcp server on your LAN, then you would need to setup that service. Using the IP of the LAN interface as the gateway, 192.168.2.1. Or if you are using static IP's then have the dhcp service send 192.168.2.1 as the gateway.

**Forwarding**

you would need to enable forwarding.

```
echo net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1 > /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Will enable forwarding for all future reboots, to enable it for the current session, run either:

```
sysctl -f
```

to read all the settings in your /etc/sysctl.conf file,  or

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

to enable just the forwarding option.

**Nat Routing**

Finally, assuming you are using NAT for the other internal devices.  you will need to add the iptables firewall entry.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o enp0s25 -j MASQUERADE
```

To make this rule apply for any future reboots, you could use iptables-persistent package, running the cmd

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

or by updating one of the many scripts that setup network configurations and links in systemd.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the eth0, without DHCP and a static IP in the same range (192.168.1.185/24) but without a default route to 0.0.0.0. then the enp0s25 addresses you change to a /32 to give it an address in the same range as your internet router and add a host route to 192.168.1.1 on the link to find the default route.

The routing decision is made on your host to use enp0s25 for anything not local, but since /32 is a single host it won't create a route to anything local. But since it needs to find your router locally you need a route onlink.

I doubt that this solution would give you any real benefit as I would struggle to completely saturated the link for long enough for me to bother about it.

```
enp0s25:
  dhcp4: no
  addresses: [192.168.1.184/32]
  routes:
    - to: 192.168.1.1
      scope: link
    - to: 0.0.0.0/0
      via: 192.168.1.1
eth0:
  dhcp4: no
  addresses: [192.168.1.185/24]
```